# How to get a notification when an audio jack is connected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04. There is no notification generated when an audio jack is connected/disconnected.

Is there any method to get such a notification?

Comment: that would require polling the jack at intervals.  it automagically toggles when you adjust the volume.  if you must have a notification look at the volume up/down code

Comment: when we connect audio jack there is any interrupt generated or there is any information available in proc file system.

Comment: i would think that would be driver/hardware specific.  it almost always adjusts when you play with volume.  polling is the best option.

Comment: thank you aking for attention.I check a function 'snd_hda_jack_detect' in hda_codec.c. In that I monitor return value of 'snd_hda_jack_detect' using printk but from that value I not get any idea about jack is connected or not. plz tell me if you have any idea about what this function return ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use Jack Sense if it has an interface you can poll but you soundcard driver must support it. 
Details are scarce on Jack Sense but you can find an interesting discussion about here:
https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-team/2011-November/017692.html

You may be interested about the list of drivers supporting Jack Sense: http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sound/alsa/HD-Audio-Models.txt